# If we don't set intent-filter to receiver, does is will handle any broadcast happens in the system?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

in android , if we didn't set intent-filter to a broadcast receiver, and we override the `onReceiver` method. does this broadcast Receiver cable to receive any broadcast message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive nothing.  :( so..

Answer (score 0):

You will receive nothing if you not add intent filter.